# Set the Host Header when using invoke-restmethod

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

For some reason this doesn't work

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost" -Headers @{"Host"="web.domain.com"}
```

I get the error

```
The 'Host' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method
```

But I can't find the method or property on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What version of powershell are you using? Your tags says 2.0, but I don't believe Invoke-RestMethod was added until 3.0.

I was able to use the exact command you provided above without error on Powershell 4.0 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I'm using powershell v3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record I worked round the issue using WebRequest

```
$bytes = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("key=value")
$web = [net.WebRequest]::Create("http://localhost") -as [net.HttpWebRequest]
$web.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$web.Host = "web.domain.com"
$web.Method = "POST"
$web.ContentLength = $bytes.Length
$stream = $web.GetRequestStream()
$stream.Write($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)
```

Comment: With this do you ever see the error "You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse"?

Comment: I am trying to create the header for cloudflare.   I am not able to determine the host and keep getting a 421 misdirected request

Answer (score 20):

This is a bug that has been fixed in [PowerShell version 4.0](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293881):

```
C:\PS> (irm http://localhost -Headers @{Host='web.domain.com'}).html

xmlns                                   head                                    body
-----                                   ----                                    ----
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml            head                                    body
```

Comment: So what's the work around? I see the table that you pasted, but I'm not sure what I'm really looking at.

Comment: This is just showing that the OP's command works in PowerShell V4 by showing the "HTML" returned by the request.  In tabular format, this is just showing the XML namespace decl and the head and body element tags.